# Why should god bless Lili St. Cyr?

Tags: music, reference, rocky-horror-picture-show, rocky-horror-show

In the song *Don't Dream It, Be It*, Janet (Susan Sarandon) finishes the number with the line

> God bless Lili St. Cyr!

[Lili St. Cyr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lili_St._Cyr) was essentially famous for getting naked a lot, especially on camera.  Although this makes it unsurprising that Frank and his protégés would admire her, it doesn't quite explain why St. Cyr is singled out for special attention.

### Why does Janet want to bless Lili St. Cyr?

Comment: [tag:reference]? I'm not sure what's referencing what here.

Comment: @armadillo - RHPS is referencing Lili St. Cyr?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be in line with the wiki excerpt for the tag, and I'm not sure you can reference a person. You can refer to a person... seems different somehow.

Comment: Is Rocky Horror sufficiently on-topic that we can ask general questions about the non sci-fi elements of it?

Comment: @armadillo - I'm not attached to it.  If you think it should be removed, feel free.  I trust your judgement.

Comment: @Valorum - Aliens with transportation rays and anti-matter laser guns inventing artificial life and using Sonic Transducers that are audio-vibratory physiomolecular devices....  I'd say yes.

Comment: @WadCheber - Arguably it's a horror film with scifi elements. Are questions **wholly unrelated to those elements** sufficiently on-topic?

Comment: I don't think it's horror at all, aside from Eddie's fate.  The whole plot is about aliens seducing and corrupting humans, being investigated by UFO hunters, etc.  The US Library of Congress lists it as Science Fiction.

Comment: @Valorum  The theme song is literally titled "Science Fiction Double Feature"

Comment: @WadCheber - But the question has nothing to do with science fiction at all. It's "Why does a song lyric reference a burlesque star?"

Comment: Existing meta consensus is overwhelming that [yes, non-SF/F elements of on-topic works are legitimate topics for questions](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/6596/1359).

Comment: @JohnP - Doesn't matter.  The movie is science fiction.

Comment: Huh. So I can ask "Why did the farmer plant an apple tree instead of another fruit in 'Farmers in the Sky'"? Weird.

Comment: @JohnP - Not familiar with that one, but there are questions about mundane elements in *Star Wars* and *Star Trek*, so, yeah, assuming that *Farmers in the Sky* is SF/F.  [Question about a joke in *Watchmen*](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/131380/was-rorschachs-pagliacci-joke-a-real-joke)

Comment: @WadCheber - You should branch out more. Robert Heinlein.

Comment: @JohnP Actually ["Farmers in the Sky"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?300091) is a sci-fi story by Rob Chilson. Heinlein wrote a book with a somewhat similar title, [*Farmer in the Sky*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1964).

Comment: Cheers for the bounty.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Out of universe (according to her biography [Goddess of Love Incarnate: The Life of Stripteuse Lili St. Cyr.](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/24796519-goddess-of-love-incarnate)) her inclusion was an homage to Richard "O'Brien" Smith's adolescent obsession with all things kitsch and glam.

The wording of the song 'Don't Dream It— Be It' (and presumably much of the rest of the film) evidently contains *multiple* in-joke references to obscure 1950s burlesque magazines.

> *Growing up in New Zealand in the 1950s, Richard Timothy Smith's
>   "adolescence was swamped with joys that most of the fifties decent
>   society decried as mindless, comics, rock-n-roll, B-movies." **He
>   became fascinated with comic books and pulp fiction, in his town of
>   Tauranga was a shop filled with kitsch and magazines. Lili St. Cyr.
>   adorned many of those magazines.***
>
> ***Smith became fascinated with her. She "was one of the most beautiful
>   women in the world and, by default, a transsexual's dream girl." Smith
>   noted that burlesque "was aimed at the eternal adolescent in males."
>   Lili clearly was the leading element of that "particular Zeitgeist."***
>
> *In 1973 Smith, now known by his stage name of Richard O'Brien, wrote
>   what would become the cult hit The Rocky Horror Picture Show, both the
>   musical and, in 1975, as a cowriter, the screenplay.*
>
> ***The character Janet, played by Susan Sarandon in the film, sings
>   "Don't Dream It— Be It." It was inspired by one of O'Brien's pulp
>   magazines asking the question, whatever happened to King Kong actress
>   Fay Wray? The last line of the song is "It's beyond me, help me,
>   Mommy — God bless Lily [sic] St. Cyr."*** And though it was just
>   twenty-five years from her heyday in the fifties, most of RHPS's
>   audience had no clue who Lili St. Cyr was. The **"inclusion of Lily
>   [sic] was driven by the recognition of my own imagined self."**
>
> *O'Brien believes the LA stage version bought some of their costumes
>   from Lili's lingerie store in 1974.*

Comment: This is the sort of answer where I can't decide whether I should bow down and cry "I'm not worthy" or give you a wedgie and shout "nerd!" ;)

Comment: You can do both. Start with the wedgie.

Comment: @Marakai - Glad you appreciated it. I rather suspect it'll earn me the bounty unless someone can persuade Richard O'Brien to come out of [twitter retirement](https://twitter.com/richardobriencm) to answer the in-universe part of the question.

Comment: *sob* You're just in it for the bounty! *shattered*

Comment: @Marakai - I've tried watching RHPS on several occasions. I don't think I've ever stayed awake all the way through, even in the middle of the day.

Comment: @Valorum You're either heck of a lot older or a heck of a lot younger than me. We used to line up for midnight viewings, the whole shebang. Never shaved my legs so couldn't wear those stockings though...